# Cannot figure out how to make a table when using Beamer

Tags: beamer

I am making a table in Beamer and attempting to use muticolumn so cal/g dry weight and cal/g wet weight appear below (with a line) average energy density, and I keep getting the following error: "./thesis.tex:93" Missing number, treated as zero. 

                    c
l.93 \end{frame}"

Here is my code (I have not inputted my data yet because I am just trying to configure my column headers):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\section{Methods and Materials}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table 1}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{c}{Tissue Type} & \multirow{2}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Average Energy Density}&\\
    \cline
    cal/g dry weight & cal/g wet weight\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Please let me know if I am not clear, and thank you for your time.

[image: This is what I am looking for specifically.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\begin{document}
\section{Methods and Materials}
\begin{frame}{Table 1}
%\frametitle{Table 1}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{Tissue Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{N} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Average Energy Density}\\
    \cline{3-4}
  & & \makecell{cal/g\\ dry weight} & \makecell{cal/g \\wet weight}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]